# Сериализация массива IplImage на С++

Tags: c++, opencv, serialize

Программа-упаковщик установочного пакета должна прочитать видео-файл в `CvCapture* capture = cvCreateFileCapture("video.mp4");`, разложить по кадрам в массив и дописать этот массив в конец установщика, который уже передаст этот массив устанавливаемому приложению.

**Как правильно выполнить сериализацию массива из объектов `IplImage`, чтобы конечное приложение имело полную информацию обо всех кадрах исходного видеофайла, могло десериализовать и использовать?**

*PS: либо, если данная затея тупиковая, прошу помощи с [этим](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/643756/opencv-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0) вопросом.*

Comment: Не ясна цель. Если вы уже получили "кадры" то что мешает вам их сериализовать. И ещё вопрос - а какой вид сериализации вы предпочитаете. Собственно у вас проблема получить "кадр" или у вас проблема сериализовать обьект "кадр" lpImage. Или у вас проблема сериализовать байт-код самой картинки кадра?

Comment: Если у вас "бинарная" сериализация, и обьект lpImage не содержит "вложений", то вам достаточно сделать write( file, lpImage , sizeof(*lpImage)). Если lpImage содержит "вложения" (массив байт, например сама собственно bmp или jpg картинка) то вам прийдётся так же сохранять каждое "вложение".

Comment: Ну, просто в структуре IplImage присутствуют указатели, и что-то мне подсказывает, что данные, на которые они указывают, не попадут в результирующий набор байт. Вот и спрашиваю, как это правильно сделать.

Comment: Да, прийдётся вам помучатся с указателями в этой структуре, вычислить размер каждого и посохранять их так же. (Если есть функция сохранения lpImage то это нужно внимательно документацию читать).

Comment: А вы не можете получить "байты" RGB кадров? Если да - вы можете их посохранять как JPG или BMP (они имеют детерминированый размер описаный в шапке). Если у вас задача показать отдельные кадры - то тогда задача упростится.

Comment: Задача проиграть при запуске конечного приложения видеофайл с наложением на него динамического текста и возможностью зациклить видео между определёнными кадрами (сделать loop). Возможно получить отдельные картинки будет логично, но насколько это "раздует" файл...

Comment: Я бы упростил так: Сделал два видео, может даже оба бы открыл и подготовил. Одно проиграл, а второе проиграл бы с зацикливанием. Наложение текста хорошо делается в отдельном "окне" (canvas) текстом с прозрачным фоном.

Comment: *Раздует файл* -  попробуйте посчитать размер занимимаемый одним lpImage, а потом размер jpg кадра. Сравните - увидите результат. И ещё момент, для "прокрутки" назад кадр может зависеть от "предыдущих" кадров, а в jpg такого не будет. Хотя... jpg может долго разжимать, прийдётся % сжатия подобрать. Вот сжатие jpg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448957/compressing-iplimage-to-jpeg-using-libjpeg-in-opencv

Comment: Да, наверно проще будет разбить видео на кадры в каком-нибудь редакторе, записать набор картинок в буфер и их потом выводить, тем более с jpeg моё приложение уже работает. Спасибо за идею

Comment: Ммм-да... 80 мб набор картинок против 17 мб mp4. Перебор...

Comment: Я думаю что с сериализацией может выйти не лучше. Тогда остаётся вариант разбить на ролики и зациклить, плюс освоить наложение текста.